# ASP.NET Editable Grid: Update register

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-post

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I'm constructing this view:

[image: Update Multiple Items]

But when I hit the 'Update' button after do some changes the web refreshes to show the original values.

**About the view:** I get this view using an IEnumerable and looping thru each item in the model inside a form. Then, inside the form, there is a table that contains only 1 row. I do this in order to wrap all the items of the record in one form. This is part of code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <form asp-action="Test" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input asp-for="@item.MchName" readonly class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            //more fields
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                      </tbody>
                   </table>
                </form>}
```

I declare an asp-action and a asp-route-id:

```
<form asp-action="Test" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
```

**Question:** Is this good enough? Is there something missing?

This is the Get Method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        PopulateMachineTypeDropDownListStore();
        return View(await _context.Machines.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

**Question:** I'm not passing any argument to the controller, yet the view will list the items following the given structure using an IEnumerable. Should I pass anything to the Get Method or is it fine as it is?

This is the Post Method:

```
        @model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine>            

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Test")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var machinetoUpdate = await _context.Machines
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            machinetoUpdate,
            "",
            s => s.MchName, s => s.StoreID, s => s.PUnit, s => s.Status))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }
        PopulateMachineTypeDropDownListStore();

        return View(await _context.Machines.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

**Question:** I don't know if because the entity I retrieve the id from  (and that I use to update the model thru TryUpdateModelAsync()) is also being used to compare to the model that thru the view this might not been working properly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your model being updated at the server when you update it? If so, what you mean to say is the view doesn't get the updated values immediately after refreshing?

Comment: The model doesnt update. The only thing that happens when I hit update is that the fields show the data they had at the begining